# update content of XML file based by attributes of an element with C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, powershell

I have got the following XML-structured data file. There is no SCHEMA or DTD available.

I wish to to workout a solution(script) that updates the content in the XML file, in between the tags  where there is nothing with a string that represents the translation of the string from the line above.

I read all references in another csv or text file with a structure like:

```
Filename ; Line ; value in between <source></source> ; value  to be entered in between <translation></translation>
```

> e.g.`<location filename="Student.txt" line="76"/>
>           <source>From</source>
>           <translation></translation>`

change to

> `<location filename="Student.txt" line="76"/>
>      <source>From</source>
>      <translation>Translation of "From"</translation>`

The  node is identified by its two attributes at the  element, **filename=**"Studentform.txt" **line=**"38".

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="en_US">
<context>
    <name>Student</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="Student.txt" line="76"/>
        <source>From</source>
        <translation></translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <name>Form</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="Studentform.txt" line="38"/>
        <source>Form</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="Studentform.txt" line="653"/>
        <source>WILLKOMMEN</source>
        <translation>WELCOME</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

I am new to XML and have a limited experience working with C#/ASP.NET.
I do not know how to handle this. During the last days, I have gone through a studying Regular Expressions (Regex), and XML (with an introduction to xPath and Schema).

I come from a data background ,  Microsoft Excel/VBA , SSRS and T-SQL.

How should I resolve this matter.Could you please guide how I can resolve the matter above and eventually, what should I study further to get it done?
Is it XSLT or C# with strings or other?

What is the simplest means to handle it? I have got two weeks to make it happen.

Thanks a million.

LATER EDIT:  I made it up. This is the working solution. Eventually I have used [LINQ to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) to convert the csv data into an array.
 Thank you very much for your guidance, stackoverflow.

```
using LINQtoCSV;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace XMLUpdater
{

    //Parse csv data to an array, csv data file= "filenName.txt". All files reside in the directory C:\XMLtool\. Make sure it exists or generate it programatically.

    class csvToParse
    {
        [CsvColumn(Name = "filename", FieldIndex = 1)]
        public string filename { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "line", FieldIndex = 2)]
        public string line { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "source", FieldIndex = 3)]
        public string source { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "translation", FieldIndex = 4)]
        public string translation { get; set; }


    }


    class csv_2_xml
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XMLtool\Students.xml");
     CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = '\t',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,

    };

     CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

     IEnumerable<csvToParse> csvStream =
     cc.Read<csvToParse>(@"C:\XMLtool\fileName.txt", inputFileDescription);


            foreach (csvToParse item in csvStream)
            {


                XElement student = doc.Descendants("student")
                    .Where(x => (x.Element("location") != null) &&
                        (x.Element("location").Attribute("filename") != null) &&
                        (x.Element("location").Attribute("filename").Value == item.filename) &&
                        (x.Element("location").Attribute("line") != null) &&
                        (x.Element("location").Attribute("line").Value == item.line.ToString())).First();
                XElement translation = student.Element("translation");

                if (translation != null)
                {
                    translation.Value = item.translation;

                }    
           }

            doc.Save(@"C:\XMLtool\Students_modified.xml");

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This has all been automated using the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  You can simply make a class and serialize it.  It does all the leg work of reading and writing the files.

Comment: What should I study to apply this? C# (which topics). Please guide me, because I wish to learn something from this problem, rather than applying a copy/paste fixture. Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer which contains an example.

Comment: Felix, what about reading from a csv and writing the <translation> values from the csv to the XML file with XmlSerializer? What pieces of study should I glue altogether to master the subject with C# in a matter of 1-1.5 weeks study time. I do not have much time available for the tasks. as actually I am some "jack of all trades" and not a dedicated (junior) C# developer.  I work primarily in the data analysis field. Thank you very much.

Comment: Reading a csv file is pretty straight forward I would think.  Read everything line by line and place in an object that can be serialized.  csv->object->serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement message = doc.Descendants("message")
                .Where(x => (x.Element("location") != null) && 
                    (x.Element("location").Attribute("filename") != null) &&
                    (x.Element("location").Attribute("filename").Value  == "Studentform.txt") &&
                    (x.Element("location").Attribute("line") != null) &&
                    (x.Element("location").Attribute("line").Value  == "38")).FirstOrDefault();
            XElement translation = message.Element("translation");
            if(translation != null)
            {
                translation.Value = "Translation of \"From\"";
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What should I do to read the "filename", "line" and "translation" with a loop   sweeping  from an external csv file? Please drive towards a documentation . thanks

Comment: You can use a Dialog Box to browses for folder name.  You need some input data to give a list of TO/FROM changes to the xml.  Yes it could come from a csv file.  If you are translating words from one language to another you may need to use the Google Language API.

Comment: what do I need to study to be able to achieve the reading from csv and write to XML within a week time span for the learning process. could you please guide me a bit? The issue is I have to achieve the functionality in 1-1.5 weeks time ( this should come as a solution, whatever technology. I went to C# because with this occasion I could have justified the time to study deeper into C#). Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know all your requirements.  It is hard to design a system by reverse engineering the little bit of information you provided..

Comment: how do I relate (x.Element("location").Attribute("line").Value  == "38")) and (x.Element("location").Attribute("filename").Value  == "Studentform.txt") with an array that results out of parsing the csv?  I mean the values of "38" and "Studentform.txt" which are the coordinates of the nodes where modification has to be done.

Comment: What ever is easiest to parse when reading the csv data.  If could be : location,line,38, location, filename, Studentform.  I don't know if you will need the tags and attribute names or just the values.  It depends on what data you are trying to change.

Comment: Can u have a look at the code I added in the body of the message? I added the reading of the csv into an array, but at the last stage I am getting a NULL error. How should I handle this?

Comment: Can you post sample of csv?  Do you have a blank row in csv that may be giving the error?

Comment: I noticed that the error of Null value goes when going in the next <context> after the 2nd

Comment: don' t understand your comment.

Comment: it is not a matter of csv structure because the code above works perfectly for the first group of attributes "filename"  and "line". It seems that the code returns the Null error value when it has to touch a node in the XML which goes far beyond ( <context> holds the <message></message> </context>. I noticed that I am getting the null error when it has to write starting from the third <context> tag . May be this more explicit.

Comment: It probably not finding the any data that is matching the search criteria so you are getting null.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the data structure of the xml. You could create a data class, then using XmlSerializer to convert the xml into an object. 
Alter convert the object back into xml

[Convert Xml with a lot of levels to one DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160903/convert-xml-with-a-lot-of-levels-to-one-datatable/37161668#37161668)

```
    public static string ToXMLString(object item)
    {
        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(item.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, item);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together some simple code snipets as an example here.  You would need to modify it to fit your needs.  See [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details about this library.

Create a class and collection to hold the object you would like to serialize:

```
public class Context
{
   public string Location {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Source {get;set;}
   public string Translation {get;set;}

}
```

Now you can have a collection of `Context` items. Let's just make it a `List<Context>`.

```
List<Context> listOfItems = new List<Context>();

var item = new Context();
item.Name = "Student";
item.Location = "Student.txt";
listOfItems.Add(item);
```

After populating and manipulating your list you can write the list to a file using the `XmlSerializer` as follows:

```
public void SaveFileXML(string filePath, List<Context> itemList)
{
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                try
                {
                    var format = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Context>));                    
                    format.Serialize(stream, itemList);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
                {
                    //Handle error
                }    
            }    
}
```

Similarly, reading a document goes like this:

```
public List<Context> ReadXml(string filePath)
{
            List<Context> result = null;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {    
                try
                {
                    var format = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Context>));
                   // deserialize returns an object so it must be cast.
                    result = format.Deserialize(stream) as List<Context>;

                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
                {
                    //Handle error
                }
            }
            return result;
}
```